# How to use GITLAB feature flag to run jobs of same stage sequentially in CI yml file

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, flags, cicd

In my project I want to run jobs of the same stage sequentially due to Hardware dependency.
The different stages are:

stages:

- build
- build install
- test

In the test stage I would like to run tests sequentially instead of the general parallel execution. According to the merge request [mentioned here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30632) the flag `Feature.enable(:ci_same_stage_job_needs)` can be used to let `needs` consider a job from the same stage as dependency.

I am facing an issue in declaring this flag in the CI. Is it possible to use this flag in the CI job ? Am I using it wrong ? If it is possible, where and how should I use it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the issue you linked, this feature has been merged into the master branch, but hasn't been released. The latest available version is [14.1.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/categories/releases/), and according to the issue this functionality and feature flag will be released in 14.2.

Answer (score 1):

A feature flag can be enable by a Gitlab Administrator:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html

For Omnibus installations:

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
```

For installations from the source:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rails console -e production
```

To enable a feature, run:

```
Feature.enable(:<feature flag>)
```

In your case:

```
Feature.enable(:ci_same_stage_job_needs)
```